# How can I use pigpio to "sniff" and collect data exchanged along an existing USB connection between two devices?

Tags: python, usb, python-3, pigpio

A controller module (power supply) for piece of scientific equipment in our lab uses a Windows program on a PC for a human interface via USB connection. I have a list of the "set" and "read" commands that are exchanged over USB.

I would like to *monitor* or *sniff* their communication with a RPi without interrupting it.

If it were RS-232 I'd just tap into the serial line, perhaps use a buffer amplifier then have [pigpio](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_serial_read_close) read for several seconds at the appropriate baud rate with something like the script below.

Once read, I'd look through the chunk of data for the particular "set" and "read" commands that I'm interested in.

Alas the connection is USB which I think poses several challenges

- data clock rate could be very high
- there may be a lot of extra information exchanged constantly that I'd have to filter out
- since it's a different protocol, there's a chance that `pi.bb_serial_read_open(pin, baud)` might not collect anything because it doesn't recognize the signal.

I don't think I can add a USB hub and use a USB to serial converter, because it would not pick up the traffic intended for a different USB device.

- Superuser SE: [How does a RS-232 to USB converter work?](https://superuser.com/q/1193105/390541)
- Electronics SE: [How do USB to serial adapters work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/427128/102305)

**Question:** How can I use pigpio to "sniff" or monitor an existing USB connection between two devices?

**update:** These suggest to me that perhaps this is just too complicated and not worth trying, but maybe I'm overreacting? I just need to capture the stream passively, and search it for a few predetermined strings.

- Reverse Engineering SE: [Where do I find a cheap hardware USB sniffer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12730/38951)
- [Building a USB protocol analyzer](https://rdist.root.org/2010/12/27/building-a-usb-protocol-analyzer/)
- [BeagleBoard/GSoC/2010 Projects/USBSniffer](https://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoard/GSoC/2010_Projects/USBSniffer)
- [Teensy - DIY USB Protocol Analyzer, Packet modifier, USB wrapper, USB over LA](https://www.plop.at/en/teensy.html)
- Kickstarter: ["OpenVizsla" Open Source USB Protocol Analyzer](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/bushing/openvizsla-open-source-usb-protocol-analyzer)

---

In response to the question in comments, I got some help from someone familiar with *Windows 7 in Chinese*. Turning on the power supply at the far end of the USB adds `USB Serial Port COM4` to the display.

[image: USB Serial Port COM4]

---

Partial example script outlining how `pigpio` can be used to collect data on a *serial line*. There's no reason to think that this would work when monitoring communications on a USB connection.

```
from binascii import hexlify
import pigpio, time

# don't forget 'sudo pidof pigpiod'

pin = 24
baud = 9600
t_collect = 3. # seconds

pi = pigpio.pi() 

try: # in case it was left open
    pi.bb_serial_read_close(pin)
except:
    pass

pi.bb_serial_read_open(pin, baud)

time.sleep(t_collect)

self.pi.bb_serial_read_close(pin)

# now read what's been collected
size, data     = pi.bb_serial_read(pin)
data_hexlified = hexlify(data)
n_hexlified    = len(data_hexlified)
```

Comment: `There's no reason to think that this would work when monitoring communications on a USB connection` ... why did you post the code then? ... it just clutters up the post

Comment: you can get a USB sniffer program for windows, but that is off topic here

Comment: @jsotola 1) "There's no reason to think that..." is to prevent comments like "That won't work for USB because it's for..." or future readers from trying to use it. The code snippet serves (among other things) to inform potential answer authors the type of familiarity I do (and don't) have.  2) I disagree it clutters up the post, and disagree that the primary value of an SE post in an engineering SE site is its *uncluttered aesthetic*. Instead more is better. Once you gain some more experience asking Stack Exchange questions you'll see that providing plenty of information is the way to go

Comment: @jsotola I've asked over 3,000 Stack Exchange questions. While rare, the only times I've gotten comments of the form "why don't you format your question the way I'd like to see it" is when the comment author has little or no experience *asking questions* and then being the recipient of comments asking for more information.

Comment: one of these may work for you ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+usb+sniffer&ia=web

Comment: i was writing a response to your response about my clutter comment and I realized that your post does not say how the windows program communicates with the scientific equiment .... how do the sofware and instrument interact? ... is it on a COM port?

Comment: @jsotola I've added some info, yes it seems that it is a USB serial COM port. Perhaps good news?

Comment: this in not in the realm of the RPi ... it is windows based ... check out http://com0com.sourceforge.net/ ... it allows the creation of virtual serial ports and allows them to be interconnected ... in your case you would connect COM4 to a virtual COM5 (for example) ... create virtual COM6 and COM7 ... connect software to COM7 ... write program to pass data between COM5 and COM6 and monitor that data

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, I'll take a look and that might be useful. But for my current needs my RPi will still need to do this.

Comment: then RPi emulates USB to serial adapter ... that would be COM4 on the windows PC ... device is plugged into RPi USB port and is seen as serial port ... write python script to pass data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pigpio can not help with sniffing data over a USB link.

There are two principal reasons.

1. pigpio can only sniff GPIO 0 to 31.  USB traffic is not connected to these GPIO.
2. pigpio can sniff data travelling at up to 500 thousand bits per second.  Modern USB traffic is several orders of magnitude faster than pigpio can handle.  Even the original low speed USB 1.0 was 1.5 million bits per second.

Comment: joan thanks for stopping by!  For point #1 I was still thinking of "tap(ping) into the (USB) line, perhaps use a buffer amplifier..." It's certainly ugly and would have to be done carefully to not upset the twisted pair transmission line inside, but in and of itself it would be interesting to try. However, point #2 confirms my fear that "data clock rate could be very high" and seems absolutely inescapable. Your answer is extremely helpful because I can now just forget about this. *Thanks!*